# How to mock service injected by HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<> in derived controller?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core, moq

I have base Api Controller defined like this

```
[ApiController]
public abstract class BaseController : ControllerBase
{
    private IMediator _mediator;

    protected IMediator Mediator => _mediator ??= HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IMediator>();
}
```

Auth controller derived from BaseController

```
public class AuthController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost(ApiRoutes.Auth.Register)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(UserRegistrationRequest request)
    {
        var response = await Mediator.Send(new UserRegistrationCommand(request.Email, request.Password));

        return Ok(response);
    }
}
```

How should mock IMediator service in unit tests? When services were injected using constructor DI I've just passed mocked services to constructor in tests, but in this scenario I'm not sure what to mock, probably HttpContext?

Comment: Use HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IMediator>() in your unit test too

Comment: Some solution without parmeterless controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mock it using a library such as Moq or NSubstitute. Then wire up the methods using these libraries.

Comment: I created mock for IMediator and setup is like this:
 _mediatorMock.Setup(mediator => mediator.Send(//somelogic);

When I used constructor DI I could just do something like this:
var controller = new AuthController(_mediatorMock.Object);

The thing is now the AuthController is parameterless.

Comment: in your class BaseController you are not using constructor injection there. IMediator is being resolved internally. You should expose it via constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this way for passing parameter to your controller or etc.

```
Mock<IMediatr> _mediatrMock;
AuthController _controller;
public AuthControllerTest()
{       
    _mediatrMock = new Mock<IMediatr>();

    var httpContext = new Mock<HttpContext>();
    httpContext.Setup(x => x.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IMediatr)))
        .Returns(_mediatrMock.Object);

    _controller = new AuthController();
    _controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext = httpContext.Object;
}

[Fact]
public async Task Register_ShouldReturnOk()
{
    var req= new UserRegistrationRequest();
    
    var result = _controller.Register(req);
    var resultObject = result as OkObjectResult;
    
    Assert.Equal(...);
}
```